# Alias for directory listing sorted by time modified in reverse order

Tags: ls

When I need to find my recently used files, this command:

`ls -lt`

lists in ascending order (by time), when there are lots files, I need to scroll to
the top to see needed files, because won't fit in terminal screen.

After finding out that `tac` inverses the output, I use: `ls -lt dir/ | tac`
Is there more fun way of doing it, without using external scripts/utils?

Answer (score 133):

The `-r` does the same thing for `ls` as `tac` does for any command which needs reverse file ordering.

So you could just write

```
ls -ltr
```

From man page:

> - `-l` List in long format. If the output is to a terminal, a total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the long listing.
> - `-r` Reverse the order of the sort to get reverse lexicographical order or the oldest entries first (or largest files last, if combined with sort by size.
> - `-t` Sort by time modified (most recently modified first) before sorting the operands by lexicographical order.

Comment: Thanks! Used `ls` for ages and never new there's -r :p

Comment: This is remembered with the handy mnemonic "later". As in, "I want to see the files that were changed later: `ls -ltr`"

Comment: Its also sad because in most other popular commands it stands for 'recursive'...

Comment: I feel a bit silly for not noticing that after looking at the man page for ls considering that the modifiers are listed in alphabetical order. In related news, there is still a recursive option for ls, but it is -R instead of -r.

Comment: just wanted to point out `ls -later` is actually a valid combination of options

Comment: @xenoterracide Just checked on ubuntu 18.04, -e is not a recognized option. What does -e do on your system?

Comment: 2 years later, no idea, but, it was either on manjaro linux, or os x.